# How to calculate Landau levels for a system e.g., Graphene numerically?

Tags: numerics

I am currently trying to calculate Landau levels for any system numerically in python. But, I am clueless about where to start rather, how to construct the Hamiltonian. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you pose your problem mathematically?